# Python 'str.contains' function not returning correct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to subset a dataframe using 'pandas' if the column matches a particular pattern. Below is a reproducible example for reference.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create Dataframe having 10 rows and 2 columns 'code' and 'URL'
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [1,1,2,2,3,4,1,2,2,5],
                   'URL': ['www.abc.de','https://www.abc.fr/-de','www.abc.fr','www.abc.fr','www.abc.co.uk','www.abc.es','www.abc.de','www.abc.fr','www.abc.fr','www.abc.it']})

# Create new dataframe by filtering out all rows where the column 'code' is equal to 1
new_df = df[df['code'] == 1]

# Below is how the new dataframe looks like
print(new_df)
                      URL  code
0              www.abc.de     1
1  https://www.abc.fr/-de     1
6              www.abc.de     1
```

Below are the dtypes for reference.

```
print(new_df.dtypes)
URL     object
code     int64
dtype: object

# Now I am trying to exclude all those rows where the 'URL' column does not have .de as the pattern. This should retain only the 2nd row in new_df from above output
new_df = new_df[~ new_df['URL'].str.contains(r".de", case = True)]

# Below is how the output looks like
print(new_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [URL, code]
Index: []
```

Below are my questions.
1) Why is the `'URL'` column appearing first even though I defined the `'code'` column first?

2) What is wrong in my code when I am trying to remove all those rows where the 'URL' column does not have the pattern `.de`? In R, I would simply use the below code to get the desired result easily.

```
new_df <- new_df[grep(".de",new_df$URL, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE), ]
```

Desired output should be as below.

```
# Desired output for new_df
                   URL  code
https://www.abc.fr/-de     1
```

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: `r"\.de"`, escape the dot.

Comment: Regarding first question, dictionary ordering is not guaranteed.  Use `df = df[['code', 'URL']]` to ensure correct ordering.  More background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. This information on dictionary is really helpful. Thanks for an alternate way of creating a dataframe too. Really appreciate it. I will keep this in mind whenever ordering is important.  I am sure a lot of people new to Python would find this very helpful, just like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the 'URL' column appearing first even though I defined the
>   'code' column first?

This is a consequence of the fact that dictionaries are not ordered. Columns are read in and created in any order, depending on the random hash initialization of the python interpreter.

---

> What is wrong in my code when I am trying to remove all those rows
>   where the 'URL' column does not have the pattern .de?

You'd need to escape the `.`, because that's a special regex meta-character.

```
df[df.code.eq(1) & ~df.URL.str.contains(r'\.de$', case=True)]

                      URL  code
1  https://www.abc.fr/-de     1
```

This may not be succifient if `de` can be found anywhere after the TLD (and not at the very end). Here's a general solution addressing that limitation -

```
p = '''.*       # match anything, greedily  
       \.       # literal dot
       de       # "de"
       (?!.*    # negative lookahead
       \.       # literal dot (should not be found)
       )'''
df[df.code.eq(1) & ~df.URL.str.contains(p, case=True, flags=re.VERBOSE)]

                      URL  code
1  https://www.abc.fr/-de     1
```

Comment: Thanks @COLDSPEED. +1 for the answers. What does the `$` sign at the end of `r'\.de$'` doing? Sorry I am new to Python and still learning a lot. will your solution work if the `.de` is not at the end? Something like this - `www.abc.de/txt`. If this was one of the values, it should not be included since it has the `.de` pattern.

Comment: @Code_Sipra In that case, use `r'\.de'` only. The `$` is an end of line anchor. I'll remove it from my answer.

Comment: You also want to exclude cases like `www.de.com` or `www.delta.com`. Ideally look for `de` after final split on `.`

Comment: @Alexander splitting on dot makes it harder, because the `\.` no longer has meaning.

Comment: I know you like a challenge... (-;  I'm just pointing out a potential issue.  Up to OP to decide if it works.

Comment: @Alexander, how do I solve that problem? You have a very valid point if I comeacross something like www.delta.com.

Comment: @Alexander You're right, I do :) How does it look now?

Comment: @Code_Sipra See edit, I've attempted to address that.

Comment: `df[~df.URL.str.split('.').apply(lambda s: s[-1].startswith('de'))]` should do the trick, excluding the `code=1` filter.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Looks fine.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the support. You guys taught me something new today!